# in another oxymoron

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can not understand the meaning of the bold sentence, specifically its "in another oxymoron" part. Help please!

The principle that any dynamic system can be measured lies at the heart of Chaos Theory, a term which sounds at first like the ultimate oxymoron. ‘Chaos theory may appear to give a fairly depressing view of the universe as a place of instability destined to dissipate under the relentless tyranny of the second law of thermodynamics,’ writes Richard Mankiewicz, but he goes on to point out how the universe is full of structures, ‘from the metronomic beat of pulsars to the exquisite convolutions in a DNA molecule.’ **Order exists, then, even if, in another oxymoron, it is disordered and complex**.

(Art and Science by Sian Ede)

Comment: I would understand "in another oxymoron" to be an aside, a parenthetic remark, which could be paraphrased "..., if I might use yet another oxymoron, ..."  (or paradox)

Comment: It's a weak attempt at word play, and probably not meant to be taken too literally.  He simply means that, though, "Chaos Theory" seems like an oxymoron, it leads (with other physics principles) to the organization of the Universe.  The "other oxymoron" presumably refers to the consideration of chaos based only on it's dictionary definition -- without considering the thermodynamic implications.

Comment: When in doubt, remove unnecessaries little by little. You're left with 'Ordered exists if it is disordered' which while technically not an oxymoron, is a contradiction, which is oxymoronic-like.

Answer (score 3):

I believe with @Tim Romano the author intends for the oxymoron to be between "order" and "disordered and complex," rather than between, as another poster has suggested, "disorder" and "complexity."

"Oxymoron" is incorrect diction here, and "paradoxically" would be better.

The "in another oxymoron" is a *metalinguistic comment* which means "to use another oxymoron," but as I pointed out above, "paradoxically" would convey *her* meaning better.

Comment: Yes, I take your point and have upvoted you. Either way the writing leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

The author is saying that describing something as "disordered and complex" is an oxymoron. This is of course nonsense as well as a misunderstanding of chaos theory. It provides me personally with an excellent reason not to read any of his books.

Comment: I didn't see the oxymoron in that combination of adjectives (disordered and complex) but in the yoking of "order exists" with "it [i.e. order] is disordered and complex". Order is disordered.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the author uses the term oxymoron, which is a special rhetoric device, in a very general sense. He says "There is order in the chaos" and he adds the idea that order and chaos are two systems or principles which are in opposition. It is a bit curious that he has no better term for this idea than "oxymoron". The term does not fit well here. The Greek term oxymoron means clever-stupid.

Answer (score 0):

rogermue says that "[t]he Greek term oxymoron means clever-stupid."  What we need here is the Greek term for ignorant-stupid.  Let me attempt again to convince you that Ede's work has no discernible meaning:

> The principle that any dynamic system can be measured lies at the
>   heart of Chaos Theory,

Can every dynamic system be measured?  A bold statement.  There are likely systems that are too small, too large, or that take too long to evolve that are beyond our capability to measure. But this hardly matters as the ability to measure a dynamic system lies not at the "heart" of Chaos Theory, the heart of which is that the smallest inevitable error in measurement makes chaotic systems impossible to predict in the long run.

> a term which sounds at first like the ultimate oxymoron.

Why would "Chaos" (let's call it disorder) be in conflict with "Theory" (which would be a scientific explanation of why there is disorder")?  It's not.  Chaotic systems arise when the forces that govern them are described by non-linear feedback equations.  There is no contradiction, real or apparent, between observing a system we can't predict and knowing why we can't predict it.

> ‘Chaos theory may appear to give a fairly depressing view of the
>   universe as a place of instability destined to dissipate under the
>   relentless tyranny of the second law of thermodynamics,’ writes
>   Richard Mankiewicz, but he goes on to point out how the universe is
>   full of structures, ‘from the metronomic beat of pulsars to the
>   exquisite convolutions in a DNA molecule.’ **Order exists, then, even
>   if, in another oxymoron, it is disordered and complex.**

Mankiewicz' statement says that instability and order exist side by side in the universe.  He does *not* say that order is disordered, nor does he mention complexity.  In fact very simple systems can display chaotic behavior.  Ede has followed the quote from Mankiewicz' with her own nonsense statement as though the former supported the latter.  But that's not the case.  And she blithely claims that she's found a second oxymoron, when she actually has established exactly none.

The last sentence has you confused because you have assumed that Ede knows what she's talking about when she discusses chaos and complexity and that she follows the standard rules of argumentation in which one cites evidence to support one's conclusions.  Neither of those things is true, so where you can understand her, she's wrong, and the rest is nonsense, essentially a private language that has no meaning that can be unlocked by the traditional keys of rhetoric, syntax, and semantics.